# How to write a MQL query to setup the alert policy if node uptime is less than 1 with 20 % nodes

Tags: monitoring-query-language

sample MQL query :

**fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| filter (metadata.user_labels.application_family == 'sample')
| align rate(1m)
| group_by [metric.instance_name], [value_uptime_mean: mean(value.uptime)]
| every 1m
| condition val() < 1**

here unable to add the condition if 20 % nodes affected out of total nodes.

help us to write a MQL query if condition value zero with number of nodes are affected more than 20 %